# Dialogue: “had” or “have”

Tags: word-choice, past-tense, dialogue

> She: I had an awesome time yesterday.
>
> He: Haha. I'm glad you **have**!

Did I use the wrong word? Is it suppose to be *had*?

Comment: Hi John, welcome to Writers SE. This is a question about language usage, and so should be migrated to English Language & Usage SE.

Answer (score 5):

Neither. The right word here is "did":

> Haha. I'm glad you ***did***!

"I'm glad you have" would work if the first sentence were: "I have had ..."